# How to return string with character at given index removed?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string, e.g.

```
string = 'foo-bar'
```

and I want a *new* string which doesn't contain the character at *index*  `3` (the `-` in the example string), so the results would be `"foobar"`. The former string must not be changed.

This is what I have so far:

```
new_string = string.dup
new_string.slice!(3)
new_string
#=> "foobar"

string
#=> "foo-bar"
```

or as a "one-liner":

```
new_string = string.dup.tap { |s| s.slice!(3) }
#=> "foobar"
```

But having to `dup` and maybe `tap` looks quite cumbersome. Is there a more concise way?

Comment: I don't know if such method exists already, but you can always _create_ one, and hide the dup/tap there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I though that I might be overlooking an obvious solution.

Comment: It certainly _feels_ that way, yes.

Comment: [Coincidentally there is a recent feature request for `dup` accepting a `tap`-like block.](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14778) Not sure if that's a good idea though.

Comment: FYI I've opened a feature request for what I think would be a viable solution to my problem: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14783

Comment: What about using `sub`? Something along the lines of: `string.sub(/(?<=.{3})./, '')`

Comment: @SagarPandya yes, that would probably work. But using a regular expression to remove a single character seems a bit much ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such a method. You can write it yourself using `slice` though.

```
at = 3
string = "abc-def"
def delete_at(string, at)
  string.slice(0, at) + string.slice(at + 1, string.length)
end

x = delete_at(string, at) #> "abcdef"
```

You could also monkey patch it to `String` class (which I don't like though)

Comment: Alternatively `string[0...at] + string[at + 1..-1]`

Comment: @Stefan yes, that would work as well. I think that `[]` is way to overloaded though. So I never use it.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: `String#[]` and `String#slice` are aliases.

Comment: @Stefan overloaded in the sense that it is used for lots of things e.g. accessing elements if an Array/Hash and my brain does not parse String[] well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems `Kernel#sprintf`can solve this fairly simply:

```
str = "foo-bar"
sprintf("%3.3s%s",str,str[4..-1])
#=> "foobar"
```

Or simply

```
sprintf("%s%s",str[0..2],str[4..-1])
#=> "foobar"
```

Additionally `Enumerable` methods could help but seem a bit overkill e.g.

```
str.each_char.with_index.reduce("")  do |memo,(s,i)| 
  i == 3 ? memo : memo << s
end
#=> "foobar"
```